# Python: unittest not running

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am working on a transpiler and wanted to try out TDD, but the tests don't seem to run. After running `python test_transpiler.py`, I get:

```
15

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

The code is:

```
import unittest
import transpiler

class TranspilerTDD:
    def test_adds_encoding(self):
        source = ""
        result = transpile(source);
        expected = "#coding: utf-8\n"
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Where `transpile` is a function in `transpiler` (which I'm sure is working).

What's wrong?

Comment: `unittest` test case classes have to inherit from `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
class TranspilerTDD:
```

to

```
class TranspilerTDD(unittest.TestCase):
```